# Using phonegap for an app for Web,iOS & Android which is more on content display

Tags: mobile, cordova, multiplatform

I am a webdeveloper. Have experiences in web development languages i.e PHP, HTML, CSS, jQuery. Ive been googling for sometime and still not clear for me if I should use phonegap.

I have a project which will be deployed in Web, iOS & Android.
The project is more on displaying data like belows :

```
User Profile (save profile / view proifle)
User Activities (displays all activities of users. get the new/latest activities everytime for display)
User Feeds (displays all feeds. get the new/latest feeds everytime for display)
User Subscription (displays all subscribers and subscribed by user)
Login/Logout/Register/Facebook Connect
```

Basically, it is more on displaying data.
So i assume the API calls will handle all the data saving and retrieval.
I will be making an API using PHP for retrieving and saving of data and i got no issue regarding this.

Also i should use a websocket/node.js kind of plugin for the realtime activities/feeds data.

All i want to know is if Phonegap fits for my needs.

We all know phonegap has many disadvantages and i want to ask the advice of experienced experts out there if Phonegap is good to go for this kind of project.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't have experience with phonegap, I'm kind of in the same boat as you. I recently started using titanium studio with the alloy mvc framework, definitely worth checking it out.

So far I have build myself a todo app working on both android and iOS, using a remote mysql database server to store my data on. They offer cloud services also, havent looked into that yet.

You can also buy modules in their store, often not that expensive and it will save you a lot of coding time.

Head over here for more information: 
http://www.appcelerator.com/